# infinite vs finite sum of holomorphic functions is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that if $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ are holomorphic on a domain $D$, then so is the sum $f(z)+g(z)$.

We can then say the finite sum of holomorphic functions is also holomorphic:

$$ h(z) = \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(z)$$

**Question:** If an infinite sum of holomorphic functions (such as a power series) doesn't diverge, it is also holomorphic. **Why?**

$$ h(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(z)$$

My uncertainty and caution is from the fact that "the limit of the sum" is not always the "sum of the limit" from elsewhere, and holomorphicity is about the existence of the derivate limit.

Comment: When you say diverge, do you mean pointwise? Or in which sense?

Comment: If you mean pointwise and we restrict to a compact domain for a moment, then the answer is no. Just use Stone-Weierstrass to approximate your favourite continuous (not holomorphic) function by a sequence of polynomials and then turn the sequence into a series via telescoping to get your counterexample.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, well, this is not quite right, because Stone-Weierstrass does not hold for (holomorphic) polynomials on an open (with compact closure) in $\mathbb C$. (For example $f(z)=\overline{z}$ is not approximable by holomorphic polynomials, etc.)

Comment: @PaulGarrett Indeed, complex conjugation happens to not be quite holomorphic... thanks for catching my blunder!

Comment: @SeverinSchraven, if you decide to delete your comment(s), I'd delete mine also, ... though I'm sure that many people have exactly the reaction to invoke Stone-Weierstrass, so some remaining cautionary note might be helpful. If you decide to delete, ping me, and I'll delete mine, too.

Comment: There are examples floating around of an infinite series of real-analytic functions whose sum is not even continuous, which implies that an infinite sum of analytic functions need not be analytic. Power series are special, however: power series are always analytic in the interior of the disk of convergence (because they converge locally uniformly).

Comment: @PaulGarrett I'll keep it :) seems like a good mistake to learn from.

Comment: @GregMartin For real-analytic functions we could use Stone-Weierstrasse (or taking some Fourier series), but how would we ensure that pointwise convergence extends to some common domain around the real axis? Is there an easy argument for that?

Comment: @GregMartin - does complex differentiability remove the pathology real-analytic functions suffer?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven - I'm afraid I'm self teaching maths and don't know the relevance of pointwise or other divergence.

Comment: @Tariq To say that your series $\sum_n f_n(z)$ converges pointwise in $D$ just means that at every $z$ in $D$ the series converges.  There are "well-known" examples, using Runge's theorem, where a series of polynomials converges pointwise to a discontinuous function, e.g. the sum might be $0$ for $\text{Re}(z) < 0$ and $1$ for $\text{Re}(z) \ge 1$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, probably you should make your comment an answer, and elaborate a bit?

Comment: @Tariq: by "real-analytic" I'm referring to the restriction of entire analytic functions to the real axis. So no: there are infinite series of entire functions where the sum is not even continuous.

Comment: For holomorphic functions uniform convergence on compact sets is enough to ensure the series sums to a holomorphic function; contrast this to the real case where uniform convergence of a series of polynomials on an interval doesn't guarantee more than continuity of the limit

Comment: If D is an open set z_0\in D and r>0 and \{z:|x

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating my comment, as requested:

Here's the standard way of showing the existence of a sequence of polynomials $g_n(z)$ that converges to $0$ for each $z$ with $\text{Re}(z) < 0$ and $1$ for each $z$ with $\text{Re}(z) \ge 0$.

Let $A_n = \{z: |z| \le n,\ \text{Re}(z) \le -1/n\}$ and $B_n = \{z: |z| \le n,\ \text{Re}(z) \ge 0\}$.  These are disjoint compact sets, and the complement of $A_n \cup B_n$ is connected.  By Runge's theorem, there is a polynomial $g_n$ such that $|g_n(z)| < 1/n$ for $z \in A_n$ and $|g_n(z) - 1| < 1/n$ for $z \in B_n$.  Now  any complex number $z$ is in $A_n \cup B_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$: if $\text{Re} (z ) \ge 0$ you just need $n > |z|$, while if $\text{Re}(z) < 0$ it's true if $n > \max(|z|, -1/\text{Re}(z))$.  And then it's easy to see that $g_n(z)$ converges to $0$ if $\text{Re}(z) < 0$ and $1$ if $\text{Re}(z) \ge 0$.

To make the sequence into a series, just take $f_1 = g_1$ and $f_n = g_n - g_{n-1}$ otherwise: we have $\sum_{k=1}^n f_k(z) = g_n(z)$.